# Using PyQt to integrate a qml based Chart to an existing ui

Tags: python, graph, qml, pyqt5, qtcharts

I am using PyQt and have the legacy application in it. In this UI based application I would like to add real time graphs defined in qml(say using QtCharts). I am able to load a basic qml file with QtQuick 2.0 and QtQuick.Controls. But I am not able to import qml files with QtCharts.

Is there any other better way of plotting real time graphs efficiently using qml on a PyQt application ?

Answer (score 2):

QtChart solution(Refer creator example qmloscilloscope)

In QML file Call python function with QML LineSeries object as argument. Property useOpenGL is supported only for LineSeries and ScatterSeries. Other series, such as BarSeries is less efficient than these two.

QML file:

```
    LineSeries{
        id: lineSeries
        name: "signal"
        useOpenGL: true
        axisX: ValueAxis {
            id: axisX
            min: 0
            max: 10
        }
        axisY: ValueAxis {
            id: axisY
            min: 0
            max: 100
        }
    }
    Timer {
        interval: 1000/25
        running: true
        repeat: true
        onTriggered: modelSpectrum.update(lineSeries)
    }
```

Python file:

```
...
@pyqtSlot(QObject)
def update(self, series):
    series.clear()
    for i in range(10):
        series.append(i, random.random()*100)
```